# How do I upload a folder of smart contracts to Remix?

Tags: remix

I'm pretty sure this used to be a feature. What am I missing?

Comment: There is a folder button on top left. From there you can choose the file yoi wish to upload. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select multiple files in the folder popup.

Answer (score 1):

You can Access a folder in Remix IDE using [Remixd](http://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_remixd_filesystem.html).

- Install [node package manager](https://nodejs.org/)
- Install remixd with `npm install -g @remix-project/remixd`
- Run it with `remixd -S <absolute-path-to-the-shared-folder>`
- Click the Chain icon top left under https://remix.ethereum.org/ and press connect
- Wait a while (I mention this because I wasn't patient when I first tried)

Comment: Thanks, however I realized you can just click the folder in normal remix and select multiple files. Not sure what happened back then.

Comment: okay. if this solved your problem you should answer your own question and press the green checkmark on your answer

Comment: remixd package name was update. Use npm install -g @remix-project/remixd